# Change origin of image coordinate system to center

Tags: python

Is it possible to change the origin of the image co-ordinate system to the image center in python? The Center of image should be (0,0).

Comment: What is your goal? You can just transform coordinate system to what you need before you take any action inside those coordinates.

Comment: My goal is to find the coordinates of the stars relative to the center of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a layout like this:

[image]

And you need to evaluate coordinates of the circles against the origin that is in the center of a rectangle.

The general approach is the following

```
new_x = old_x - center_x
new_y = old_y - center_y
```

So the results would be:

```
red = (-7, -18)
yellow = (15, -12)
green = (0, 8)
```